# Is there a V8 CommonJS implementation that I can use as a library?

Tags: javascript, v8, commonjs

I am working on a game engine with V8 bindings. While I have some simple functions for reading and writing files etc. it would be great if there was a drop-in library that adds the CommonJS stuff.

Is there a project working on that? While there are a number of implementations listed on www.commonjs.org, they are all part of a framework like node.js.

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999974/will-existing-javascript-frameworks-incorporate-commonjs

Answer (score 1):

The [node-commonjs](https://github.com/kriszyp/node-commonjs) project implements CommonJS on top of node.js, which uses the V8 engine as its platform.